# REST API Authentification

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, endpoint

I am trying to authenticate to a [REST API](https://github.com/sorare/api) with a post method as stated in their docs. I am doing so using python; I get the error

```
Bad Request: 784: unexpected token at 'user=email&user=password'
```

Here is my code, any ideas?

```
import requests
import bcrypt

user = 'my@email.com'
password = 'mypassword'

#getting salt from server
response = requests.get("https://api.sorare.com/api/v1/users/{0}".format(user))

#getting CSRF token and session
salt = response.json()['salt'].encode('utf-8')
csrf_token = response.headers['CSRF-TOKEN']
_sorare_session_id = response.headers['Set-Cookie'].split(',')[2].split('=')[1].split(';')[0]

#hashing the password using salt
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)

#Paylod and headers
payload = {
    "user": { "email": user, "password": hashed.decode('utf-8') }
}
headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "X-CSRF-Token": csrf_token,
  "_sorare_session" : _sorare_session_id
}


#trying authenticate
response = requests.post("https://api.sorare.com/users/sign_in.json", data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to convert the payload to json string

```
import json
payload = json.dumps(payload)
```